# Bounds for PNT from Wiener-Ikehara?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis, tauberian-theorems

1. What sort of bounds on the error term in the Prime Number Theorem can one obtain through a Wiener-Ikehara approach?
2. Same question, but for the Mertens function $M(x)=\sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n)$.

Answer (score 9):

The Wiener-Ikehara approach to PNT (as an asymptotic statement $\pi(x) \sim x/\log x$) only needs the nonvanishing of $\zeta(s)$ on ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1$, nothing about its growth conditions. I don't think you can expect an error term in PNT just from the minimal assumption of no zeros on ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1$.

If you allow some growth conditions on ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1$ then error terms can be given. See the following three papers, with MathSciNet reference numbers at the end of each.

1. J. Čížek, On the proof of the prime number theorem, *Časopis Pěst. Mat*. **106** (1981), no. 4, 395–401, 436. (MR0637818)
2. A. Grant, Fourier transforms and the P.N.T. error term,
   *Časopis Pěst. Mat*. **112** (1987), no. 4, 337–347. (MR0921321)
3. A. Grant, A further note on the P.N.T. error term,
   *Časopis Pěst. Mat.* **112** (1987), no. 4, 348–350. (MR0921322)

For $\pi(x) - {\rm Li}(x)$, the first paper got the error term $O(x/(\log x)^n)$ for all positive integers $n$ using only information about the zeta-function on ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1$: the nonvanishing and upper bounds on all $|\zeta^{(k)}(s)|$ and on $|1/\zeta(s)|$ away from a neighborhood of $s=1$. The second paper got error term $O(xe^{-g(x)})$, where $g(x) = (1/25)(\log \log x)^2/\log\log\log x$ The third paper got error term $O(xe^{-g(x)})$, where $g(x) = L(\log x)^{1/12}$ for some $L > 0$.

Comment: Thanks! But how would you show upper bounds on $|\zeta^{(k)}(s)|$ and $|1/zeta(s)|$ without proving a zero-free region? Isn't that equivalent?

Comment: (Just for fun: I already knew how to prove PNT, and bounds on $M(x)$, to strength $O(x/(\log x))^k$ using that information. I'll have to read further to know whether the method is the same.)

Comment: What I had was not too different from the first proof in Čížek (credited to Titchmarsh). Isn't the second proof close to the first one, with a change of variables so that we are now on the real line? (The version of the proof given in Čížek is not self-contained; I'll need to go to his sources.)

Comment: @HAHelfgott Yes, a lower bound on $1/|\zeta(1+it)|$ is equivalent to a zero-free region, that's just by continuity.  But if you want to use only Wiener-Ikehara and nonvanishing for Re$(s)\geq 1$ with no "deeper" estimates $\zeta(s)$, then you provably cannot get an effective error term in PNT (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.03491).

Comment: Just by continuity?

Comment: @2734364041 can you post an expanded version of your comment as an answer? The paper you mention appeared in Proc. AMS in 2018 (MR3866849) and there was a follow-up paper with explicit counterexamples in 2021 (see https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.01635 and MR4211861).

Comment: @HAHelfgott To be clear, I am not making the claim that "the standard" zero-free region would follow by continuity alone.  I am only saying that "some" zero-free region would follow by continuity alone.  This is a fact about continuous functions that follows from the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition.  That's why I used the less article "a" instead of "the" in my comment.

Comment: Ah, sure, that's clear. I wouldn't be surprised if the standard zero-free region followed from $|\zeta'(s)/zeta(s)|\ll \log \Im s$ and $|1/\zeta(s)|\ll \log \Im s$, however. Does it?

Comment: @HAHelfgott That is sufficient.

Comment: I think $|\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s)| \ll \log |\Im(s)|$ (for $\sigma > 1$) is itself sufficient,  at least if you have a cheap version of the convexity bound like $|\zeta(s)| \ll |\Im(s)|^{O(1)}$. (E.g., use the form of Jensen's formula in Lemma 8.6(a) of Koukoulopoulos' "The Distribution of Prime Numbers" and take real parts of both sides?)

Comment: The MVT makes the continuity argument in @27343's comment quantitative, and in fact "prove a ZFR for $\zeta(s)$ by showing a lower bound for $\zeta(s)$ and an upper bound for $\zeta'(s)$" is basically the approach taken in Koukoulopoulos' pretentious ZFR proof.  (He works with the "pre-sifted" functions $\zeta_y(s) = \prod_{p > y} (1-p^{-s})^{-1}$ to leverage the fact that in the worst case for the upper bound for $\zeta'(s)$, one obtains an improvement to the lower bound for $\zeta(s)$.)

Answer (score 7):

Per KConrad's suggestion, I am turning my comment into an answer.

The Wiener-Ikehara tauberian theorem states that if $S:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a non-decreasing function and
$$F(s) = \int_1^{\infty}S(x)x^{-s}\frac{dx}{x}$$
converges for Re$(s)>1$ and that there exists $a\in\mathbb{C}$ such that
$$F(s)-\frac{a}{s-1}$$
continuously extends to Re$(s)\geq 1$, then
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{S(x)}{x}=a.$$
On the other hand, a version of the Ingham-Karamata tauberian theorem states that if $S:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz continuous on its domain and $F(s)$ analytically continues across the line Re$(s)=0$, then
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}S(x) = 0.$$
It is reasonable to ask if these two results can be interpolated.  That is, if $F$ has a pole at $s=1$ of order at most 1 with residue $a$ (equal to zero if no pole exists) and there exists a constant $\delta>0$ such that
$$F(s) - \frac{a}{s-1}$$
analytically continues to the region Re$(s)\geq 1-\delta$, *do tauberian arguments alone ensure that there exists a constant $0\leq c(\delta)<1$ such that*
$$S(x) = ax+O(x^{c(\delta)})?$$
The answer is **no**.  This was proved by [Debruyne and Vindas](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.03491v2).  One needs additional information on $F$, such as quantitative upper and lower bounds on $F$ and/or its derivatives in the region of analytic continuation.  Without such information, the rate of convergence in the above tauberian results is in fact optimal (which can be quantified as an $\Omega_{\pm}$ statement), and one can construct examples of $S$ and $F$ that show this.  See the follow-up paper by [Debruyne, Vindas, and Broucke](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.01635v2).

This means that if you want a nontrivial error term in the prime number theorem via tauberian methods, even if you assume RH, then you must have more information about $\zeta(s)$, probably in the form of quantitative upper and/or lower bounds in the zero-free region you use/assume.  I think that it is likely (but I do not know definitively) that any upper and/or lower bound that you insert into a tauberian proof would yield a better error term in the prime number theorem if instead you insert said bounds into an "explicit formula".  You could also proceed as in the largely elementary (and quite beautiful) proof of the prime number theorem on page 40 of Iwaniec and Kowalski's book *Analytic Number Theory*.  (I say "largely elementary" because they use Fourier inversion.  But everything in their proof does take place in the region Re$(s)>1$.)

Comment: It *is* beautiful. When you say that it uses Fourier inversion, you mean - to establish $\log^+ y = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{(\sigma)} y^s s^{-2} ds$, right?

Comment: To prove the prime number theorem with Tauberian theorems, they are applied to $F(s) = -\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$, to which a hypothesis of analytic continuation for $-\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s) - 1/(s-1)$ to a half-plane ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1 - \delta$ is not practical, because it requies a zero-free half-plane for $\zeta(s)$ with a uniform width to the left of  ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$. Was there a typographical error in your hypothesis of a region of analytic continuation for $F(s) - a/(s-1)$?

Comment: @HAHelfgott yes.

Comment: @KConrad I was essentially quoting the papers that I cited.  They do not prove their results specifically for PNT / $\zeta(s)$, but in much greater generality.  The point is that a uniform-width region of analytic continuation alone is insufficient to extract a nontrivial error term; one must need specific information on $F$.  If this holds for regions of uniform width, then I imagine that the proof can be modified (perhaps obnoxiously) to establish the same conclusions for non-uniform width.  This is cumbersome to quantify for ALL possible ZFR's for $\zeta'/\zeta$.

Comment: @KConrad but your comment illustrates the point; tauberian theorems are indeed inefficient for the PNT if you care about the quality of the error term (besides knowing that it is $o($main term$)$).

Comment: Okay, I see now what the significance is: even assuming a zero-free region that's a strip of uniform width is not enough in the general setting of Tauberian theorems to expect to get an error term any better than of $o$-type.

Comment: @KConrad Exactly.  I was very surprised by all of this.  I hoped one day to prove an "effective" version of Wiener-Ikehara with an error term depending uniformly on the boundary of the region of analytic continuation.  That being said, there is a proof of the PNT where the quality of the error term depends uniformly on the ZFR, even when the ZFR does not have uniform width.  (This is why I was hopeful.)  See Theorem 1.1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.09515 (proved in much broader context than just the PNT).